# How to store 3 different types in a sequential container (e.g., std::vector)

Tags: c++, types, typechecking, std-variant

I'm working on a problem (it's essentially an encoding problem), where the encoded type can be one of the 3 types:

1. The first type is fully described by 2 `int8_t`s. I can use `std::pair` to contain this or use a struct.
2. The second type can be fully described by a boolean.
3. The third type can be described by an integral value that takes on values in `{0, 1, 2, 3}`, so basically a `uint2_t` (if that exists). I can use a struct to contain this.

The issue I am having is I need to store all instances of the encoded type in some sequential container (ideally a `std::vector<T>`), but I'm having some trouble figuring out how to do this in a clean way.

I think I can use `std::variant` to represent the 3 types, or define a custom struct, perhaps with a `kind` member attribute (along with the attributes necessary to represent the 3 types) that tells me which one of the 3 types is being represented in an instance of the `struct`. The former seems like it's going to involve a lot of "type checking" using `std::variant` methods, and the latter is a lot of wasted memory.

Are there other approaches that can work here?

Comment: `std::variant` is perfectly suited to what you have describe. Why do you think it's a lot of work to use it? Perhaps update your question with your specific concerns against using it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau It may not be a lot of work, but I was envisioning having to do a lot of checking against pointers to see which type is being represented. I was thinking that'd clutter the code, but I'll write it out and see if it's as much clutter as I'm initially envisioning. Still open to other suggestions

Comment: The C keyword `union` is how you reserve memory for different types in a data structure efficiently.  Though, if you're going to use a `union`, and this is the first time you've learned about it, you should think much harder about why you need it.

Comment: @VoNWooDSoN `std::variant` is basically a type-safe `union`. A `union` in C behaves differently in C++, so you have to be really careful with it.

Comment: If it ends up as a lot of clutter, post the code and we can see if there is a more elegant solution

Comment: Agreed.  I think that `std::variant` is the most correct path forward.

Answer (score 1):

> The former seems like it's going to involve a lot of "type checking" using `std::variant` methods, and the latter is a lot of wasted memory.

The latter could be a `struct` with a one byte member telling you which of the other members that is active - and the other members could be placed in a `union` so that only memory for the largest member is required.

As it happens, that's what a `std::variant` is - so use that.

As for a lot of type checking, you could use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) to build up an effective checking mechanism behind the scenes so that you don't have to clutter your code with that too much.

Example (similar to one of the examples in the `std::visit` link):

```cpp
#include <variant>

template<class... Ts>
struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

using T1 = std::pair<int8_t, int8_t>;
using T2 = bool;
enum class T3 : unsigned char {zero, one, two, three};

int main() {
    std::variant<T1, T2, T3> v;

    v = true;

    std::visit(overloaded{
        [](T1 p) { std::cout << "got pair\n"; },
        [](T2 b) { std::cout << "got bool\n"; },
        [](T3 e) { std::cout << "got enum\n"; }
    }, v);
}
```

Output:

```
got bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the obvious solution is `std::variant`.

```cpp
struct A {
    std::int8_t a, b;
};
using B = bool;
using C = std::uint8_t; // enough to represent {0, 1, 2, 3}, no smaller type available

std::vector<std::variant<A, B, C>> stuff;
```

Besides `std::variant`, it's also feasible to store a `std::array<std::uint8_t>, 2>` and just treat it as one of the three types when needed.
Depending on your needs, you don't even need to store which "union member" is active then.

You can obviously use a plain `union` of `A`, `B`, and `C` as well.

Comment: `C` could be an `enum class` whose base type is `(unsigned) char` or `std::(u)int8_t`. You can't get a type smaller than that.

Comment: just want to confirm that `std::variant<A, B, C>` doesn't actually reserve memory for all 3 types, and will only reserve memory for the type it's actually representing?

Comment: `std::array<std::uint8_t>, 2>` i think this could work as well. I guess ideally type `C` should use less memory than type `A` for my problem

Comment: @24n8 `std::variant` is basically a type-safe `union`, and just like with a `union`, a `std::variant` will reserve the size of its largest element type. Whichever type is assigned to the `variant` will occupy that memory.

Comment: @24n8 the `std::variant` reserves memory for the largest of the three types, which is presumably `A`, as well memory for an extra index which keeps track of which member is active. To be honest, that index is probably the most costly thing here. If you can't afford it and you don't need to test at runtime which member is active (because for some reason, you always know anyway), you can use a plain `union`.

Comment: @JanSchultke the OP did not say they wanted `C` to hold 4 integers of 2 bits each.  They said it is a single integer that has 1 of 4 possible values.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you're right. In that case, a single `std::uint8_t` also works.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using variant to discriminate against the types and `enum` for the last type. Having `enum` for the last will help detect certain bugs at compile time.

```cpp
#include<variant>
#include<cstdint>
#include <utility>

using first = std::pair<int8_t, int8_t>;
using second = bool;
using third = enum {zero, one, two, three};

int foo() {
    std::variant<first, second, third> V;
}
```